# Adding views to MuPDFReaderView

Tags: java, android, mupdf

I am currently using the MuPDF library from here: http://www.mupdf.com/

I've successfully compiled the library and everything is working great, though I am at a loss on how to achieve the following.

I want to attach views, such as button views, textviews, webviews and imageviews to the MuPDFReaderView. But everytime I try to add the view I fail to get any visible results, I can not see the attached view anywhere and I'm sure it's being added because when I debug it, the code is successfully run.

The reason I want to do this is to overlay views on the PDF view which will then scale and move along with the PDF document.

I ofcourse realise there isn't any code in this question, but I can't really post the entire MuPDF source code here, so here's what I think is relevant in a pastebin:
http://pastebin.com/qJFNsvdV

So yeah, how and where would I attach views to the document so they scale and move with the document properly?

Answer (score 0):

We have a similar feature in our Android customizable magazine app, using muPDF: we add views on top on the pdf view to display slide shows or videos inside a magazine page.
This app is open source and available on [Github](https://github.com/libreliodev/android). It should be easy for you to review the code, and see how we implemented this feature.

Comment: Thanks for your comment, I was able to successfully attach views to the document after some trial and error earlier today. Thanks anyways!